# How to pass credentials to AWS STS GetSessionToken

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sts

I wrote a javascript file manager to manage user files on an Amazon S3. It uses the AWS Javascript API. Developed it using hard-coded IAM user credentials, and now for production want to use temporary credentials Instead.

My plan is for our PHP server to generate the temp credentials from the IAM credentials, via AJAX callback from the JS code to PHP via STS GetSessionToken. Seems simple enough, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to pass the IAM key/secret to GetSessionToken in the URL. The examples in the AWS docs all show something like:

> https://sts.amazonaws.com/?Version=2011-06-15&Action=GetSessionToken&DurationSeconds=3600&AUTHPARAMS

Where I guess "AUTHPARAMS" is so obvious that I should not need any further explanation. But sadly, I do need further explanation. All I need from the PHP side of things is this one little call, so I didn't really want to install the whole AWS PHP SDK just for this. If I can just find out how to build the URL for this one call, then I can send it off via CURL and be all set. At least that was the plan.

Is there a way to call GetSessionToken directly via the REST api, and pass it the IAM key/secret, or is it really more complicated than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about [AWS API request signing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html). More specifics [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html). Note that AWS regions opened after January 30, 2014 require v4 signing, while earlier regions accept v2 or v4 signing.

Or just use the PHP SDK which makes it all much simpler.

Comment: By signing the "request", do you mean signing the GetSessionToken request made from PHP? That's ok if that's the way to do it, rather than passing key/secret as parameters. But I don't want to have to sign every request made on the javascript side.

Comment: I guess nearly every request is signed one way or another, usually by one of the API wrappers. So, once I get the temporary credentials from PHP, and send them to the JS API, that API in the browser will be able to use those temp credentials to sign all its aws calls automatically, without further need for php callbacks. Is that pretty much how it should work?

Comment: I think you have an off-by-2 error, here @jarmod.  The signature version for regions launched during or after 2014 is V4, older regions support V4 or V2.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Wow, don't know what I was doing there! Thanks for the correction Michael, have updated.

Comment: @DaveInMaine Yes, provide temporary creds to the JS SDK browser-side. To get a minimal in-browser SDK, see https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/. Also read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html#api_getsessiontoken.

Comment: @DaveInMaine also note that [`AssumeRole`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) seems substantially more appropriate than `GetSessionToken`; the former creates credentials whose privilege is restricted by those of the role and a passed policy, while the credentials from the latter can be (ab)used to do anything the IAM user can do.